# Set value range for add/minus button for form submit

Tags: jquery, forms

I found the script below to change quantity for a form submit. However, it allows values below 0. Is there a way to set a range (example: between 1 to 10)?

```
<div class="add_minus_button">
  <input type='button' value='-' class='minus' />
  <input type='text' class='value' value='0' name='item' />
  <input type='button' value='+' class='plus' />
</div>

<script>
   $('.minus, .plus').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();    
      var $input = $(this).siblings('.value');
      var val = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
      $input.val(val + ($(this).hasClass('minus') ? -1 : 1));
  });
</script>
```

Here is the jsfiddle [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelyuen/99WUG/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.minus, .plus').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    var $input = $(this).siblings('.value');
    var val = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
    var isminus = $(this).hasClass('minus');
    if((isminus && val > 5) || (!isminus && val <10)) // 5 is minimum and 10 is maximum
        $input.val(val + (isminus ? -1 : 1));
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99WUG/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.minus, .plus').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    var $input = $(this).siblings('.value');
    var val = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
    var isminus = $(this).hasClass('minus');
    if((isminus && val > 1) || (!isminus && val <10))
        $input.val(val + (isminus ? -1 : 1));
});
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/99WUG/2/

Comment: Isn't this an exact duplicate of my answer?

Comment: @Jcl Yes it is what I change was if((isminus && val > 1) while yours was if((isminus && val > 5) only